# Changing SeekBar Thumb/Pointer speed

Tags: android, seekbar

Google has failed me on this issue. I am researching if it is possible to change the Pointer/Thumb speed of a `SeekBar`. Example: I slide my finger half way across the screen, but the Pointer only moves a quarter. 
An idea I have is to raise the distance needed to move the `SeekBar` thumb in the `OnStartTrackingTouch()` method and reset it in the `OnStopTrackingTouch()` mehtod. But I don't know how to tackle this problem.

Comment: did you have any implementation of this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the SlimKat Rom 4.4.4. Jubakuba implemented a fine control seekBar. [Github link](https://github.com/alteredlikeness/slim_frameworks_base/commit/f0f290f0b7f55b5d16bb91f84a24fe043d01a7c3)

Answer (score 0):

The indicator on the seekbar changes with the percentage of the current value to the max value.  So if you cut the max value of the seekbar in half, the indicator will be twice as "sensitive".

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the Thumb still moves at the same speed. The MX Player has a wonderful example of what I am looking for. The progress bar sliding speed depends on the y-coordinate, the higher you move your finger the slower the video rewinds.